# Exclude a category woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce website, i display each category in my home page.
My category tree is like :

- Parent category (ID:23)
- -sub cat
- -sub cat
- -sub cat

I would like to exclude the parent category

Please find my code :

```
<div class="row">
  <?php 
    $prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
     ));
    
    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
    $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $shop_catalog_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, $size = 'large' );
    $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $shop_catalog_img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" /><h2><?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?></h2></a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    
</div>
```

could you please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with this line

```
'exclude' => array( ID_cat ),
```